# Why is Australia in the Eurovision Song Contest 2018 when they aren't in Europe?

Tags: eurovision-song-contest

If you don't know, the Eurovision Song Contest is

> the longest-running annual international TV song competition held among the member countries of the European Broadcasting Union.

So why are Australia participating when they are not in Europe and not part of the European Broadcasting Union??

Comment: Well. it's identified as an "**international** TV song competition".

Comment: held among the member countries of the European Broadcasting Union @madmada

Comment: They can still held and international or a world wide award, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'rules' around the competition are fairly relaxed and fully under the control of the EBU.  The EBU clearly allows itself to invite other broadcasters to join the competition by special invitation.

The EBU boundaries already go well beyond the geography of Europe, with member broadcasters from Israel, Jordan and Algeria.

The inclusion of Australia first happened in 2015. This [Eurovision Press release and FAQ](https://eurovision.tv/story/australia-to-compete-in-the-2015-eurovision-song-contest) goes into more details but it states:

> Australia’s Eurovision Song Contest participation is a one-off initiative. But throughout its 60 years of development, new elements have been introduced to keep the Eurovision Song Contest exciting, surprising and relevant to the spirit of time. Who knows what the future will bring, as excitement about this European tradition spreads to other countries around the world?

Which indicates that the door was open for such a repeat of this event or for future invitations to other countries as well.  Australia has subsequently taken part in the 2016 and 2017 competitions.

The FAQ also states that

> Broadcaster SBS from Australia is also an Associate Member of the EBU.

Associate members come from countries all over the world.

Comment: Azerbaijan is in Europe for Formula 1 too ;-) oh, retract that - apparently it's officially in both Europe & Asia...

Comment: @Tetsujin ... wow, its to the east of Turkey and the approximately the same latitude as Turkey, a county that almost defines the Europe / Asia border at the Bosphorus.  I would have put it in Asia, not Europe.

Comment: Me too - & in fact did, until I got all 'googly' about it, just to try see how they justified it as being the new home of the European F1 race the past couple of years.